# representing matrixes as an array using Jama

Tags: java, matrix, jama

I'm using Jama to calculate eigenvectors and eigenvalues, and it works quit well.

The problem is that sometimes extracting the columns from the matrix into an array results in wrong values.

Have someone came accross it? How shall I deal with it?

I'm attaching the code I used:

```
import weka.core.matrix.EigenvalueDecomposition;
import weka.core.matrix.Matrix;

public class Main6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] m = {{1,0,1},{0,1,0},{1,1,1}};
        EigenvalueDecomposition e = new EigenvalueDecomposition(new Matrix(m));

        double[] imgValue = e.getImagEigenvalues();
        double[] realValue = e.getRealEigenvalues();

        double[] columns = e.getV().getColumnPackedCopy();
        int rowDim = e.getV().getRowDimension();

        for(int i = 0; i<e.getImagEigenvalues().length; i++){
            System.out.println("\n<"+imgValue[i] + "," + realValue[i]+">");
            for(int j=i*rowDim;j<(i+1)*rowDim;j++)
                System.out.print(columns[j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n"+e.getV());

    }
}
```

Wheares the results are:

```
    OUTPUT:

    <0.0,2.0>
    0.7071067811865475 0.0 0.7071067811865475 
    <0.0,0.0>
    -0.7071067811865475 0.0 0.7071067811865475 
    <0.0,1.0>
    -1.0 1.0 -2.220446049250313E-16 

    According to the debugger, the matrix is:
      0.71 -0.71 -1   
      0     0     1   
      0.71  0.71  0   


    the matrix is:

      1 0 1
      0 1 0
      1 1 1
```

I would really appreciate any advice or insight regarding why it happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have mixed up you X and Y axis some where (rows vs columns)  I am not sure which one is correct. If you "debug" output is produce by `toString()` that is likely to be correct.

Comment: That is not the problem.
I wish that was the case, but I found a more severe issue.
For the matrix {{1,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,1}} 
both the debugger and both the ouput are the same:
1.618033988749894:
v1 = -0.6479361632942984 0.0 -0.40044657145607854 -0.6479361632942985 
-0.6180339887498949:
v2= 0.4880538916195737 0.0 -0.7896877849821275 0.4880538916195736 
1.0:
v3 = 2.220446049250313E-16 0.0 1.2054651028791157E-16 1.4142135623730951 
1.0:
v4 = 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0}.
It is the variable types which is problematic:  what is the double 2.220446049250313E-16 or 1.2054651028791157E-16?

Comment: The dimensions don't appear to be the same.  I would assume the values less than |x| < 1e-15 are to be printed as 0.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for your help!
I Must ask- how did you came up with the boundry  |x| < 1e-15?

Comment: double has about 15-16 digits of accuracy.  Matrix operations can involve lots of calculations so there is a high chance of errors. My rule of thumb is that for every power of calculations you lose about one digit. e.g. you have ~10(so you lose a digit) and your magnitudes are about 1 so you have about 15 digits of accuracy after 1. If your matrix was larger and you were doing about 100 calculation you would have 14 digits and for 1000 calcs you would have about 13 digits and if your magnitudes were about 1000 you would have an accuracy down to about 1e-10. (1e-16 * 1000 calcs * 1000 mag)